# i am trying to add name and number in my recyler view contact list but when i click add button the app stop working and close

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview

MainActivity of my code

```
package com.example.recycleview;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayList<ContactModel>arrContact= new ArrayList<>();
RecyclerContactAdapter adapter;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
FloatingActionButton btnOpndlg;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         recyclerView= findViewById(R.id.recycleContact);
        btnOpndlg = findViewById(R.id.btnopndlg);
        btnOpndlg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_update);

                EditText edtname= dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtname);
                EditText edtno= dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtno);
                Button btnActn= dialog.findViewById(R.id.addbtn);
                btnActn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        String name=" ", number="";

                        if(!edtname.getText().toString().equals("")){
                             name= edtname.getText().toString();

                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter the name ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        if(!edtno.getText().toString().equals("")){
                             number= edtno.getText().toString();

                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter the number ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        arrContact.add(new ContactModel(name,number));
                         adapter.notifyItemInserted(arrContact.size()-1);
                        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(arrContact.size()-1);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                });
                dialog.show();

            }
        });



        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        arrContact.add(new ContactModel(R.drawable.ap,"Shank","908784836"));
        arrContact.add(new ContactModel(R.drawable.lp,"Luffy","908784836"));
        arrContact.add(new ContactModel(R.drawable.kl,"Aurther","908784836"));
        arrContact.add(new ContactModel(R.drawable.ss,"madara","908784836"));
        arrContact.add(new ContactModel(R.drawable.gp,"mob","908784836"));
        arrContact.add(new ContactModel(R.drawable.hp,"Sakuna","908784836"));
        arrContact.add(new ContactModel(R.drawable.gp,"mob","908784836"));
        arrContact.add(new ContactModel(R.drawable.ap,"Shank","908784836"));
        arrContact.add(new ContactModel(R.drawable.lp,"luffy","908784836"));
        arrContact.add(new ContactModel(R.drawable.ss,"madra","908784836"));
        arrContact.add(new ContactModel(R.drawable.ss,"madra","908784836"));
        arrContact.add(new ContactModel(R.drawable.ap,"shank","908784836"));
        arrContact.add(new ContactModel(R.drawable.gp,"mob","908784836"));

RecyclerContactAdapter adapter= new RecyclerContactAdapter(this, arrContact);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.recycleview, PID: 2731
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.recycleview.RecyclerContactAdapter.notifyItemInserted(int)' on a null object reference
at com.example.recycleview.MainActivity$1$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:59)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1219)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

please check the above code mainacitvity

Comment: You are not assigning to the correct ```adapter``` in this line ```RecyclerContactAdapter adapter= new RecyclerContactAdapter(this, arrContact);```.

Comment: no the adapter is correct

Comment: So, you have already removed ```RecyclerContactAdapter``` at that line but still having the same problem?

Comment: from which line i have to remove RecyclerContactAdapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the very beginning of your code, you have declared a variable:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<ContactModel>arrContact= new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerContactAdapter adapter; // You have declared an adapter here
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    FloatingActionButton btnOpndlg;

    ...
}
```

But close to the end of your code, you have defined another `adapter`:

```java
RecyclerContactAdapter adapter= new RecyclerContactAdapter(this, arrContact);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The above will only create a new local variable and keeps your top `adapter` being `null`.

So if you would like to access `adapter` in any function within the same class, you should assign to your top declared `adapter`. And therefore you should remove `RecyclerContactAdapter` for the bottom one:

```java
adapter = new RecyclerContactAdapter(this, arrContact);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

adapter don't assign obj,you need Assigns a value to a declared variable.

```
  adapter = new RecyclerContactAdapter(this, arrContact);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a check, if it's null or not

```
if(adapter !=null) {
    adapter.notifyItemInserted(arrContact.size()-1);
}
```